# How to replace or substitute one column of data with their corresponding value from a list

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, google-sheets-arrays

I'm trying to replace a column of data (`Prodct SKU`) on one sheet (a) with the corresponding value taken from 2 columns on sheet (b) (`Product SKU & Product ID`).

I've attached the spreadsheet to help illustrate:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NigG0GoB1Im-gubwak2q3tpqo-8KmSCy-SusP9Ps6bs/edit?usp=sharing

e.g. on column A Sheet A (`Product Sku`) search for the corresponding `Product ID` (column B sheet B) and enter the corresponding `Product ID` value on Sheet A column B (`Product ID`).

Current formula : `=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(A1:A,SheetB!A1:C,{2,3},0)),)`

We'll have hundreds of products codes which will be added to frequently.

I've tried reading various online answers but I'm very confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easier way to solve the problem is to remove the blank rows below the data range (from row 12 to the last row of the sheet)

---

Removing `IFERROR` the cell with the formula shows the following error

[image]

Replacing `A1:A` by `A1:A11`

[image]

If we replace `A1:A11` by `A2:A12` we get the following

[image]

Comment: That's great Ruben thanks so much!  all seems to be working perfectly :)  Saved me lots of time!